# How do I get default props in custom input field in vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I want to make custom input component of default input like this.

```html
<template>
  <input  type="text"> 
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "CustomInput",
}
</script>
```

How can I add all prop which is default of  automatically without define. example if  I set placeholder on **CustomInput** then this placeholder automatically apply on **input** Where I doesn't need to write placeholder as prop in component CustomInput.

```html
<CustomInput placeholder="test"/>
//it will be apply like 
<input placeholder="test"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a component's *root element* automatically [inherits attributes](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#attribute-inheritance) applied to the parent, so the behavior you're seeking already occurs. For attribute inheritance to work, there can only be a single root element. Even an adjacent comment element will disable the inheritance.

```html
<!-- input inherits attributes -->
<template>
  <input /> 
</template>

<!-- No attribute inheritance -->
<template>
  <!-- my comment -->
  <input />
</template>

<!-- No attribute inheritance -->
<template>
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input id="password" type="password" ​/>
  ​<p>Enter a unique password</p>
</template>
```

When you can't rely on attribute inheritance (e.g., multiple root elements exist, or the target is nested within other elements), you can [disable the attribute inheritance](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance) with the `inheritAttrs=false` option, and use `v-bind="$attrs"` on the target element:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" v-bind="$attrs" ​/>
 ​   <p>Enter a unique password</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
}
</script>
```

Also note that `v-model` doesn't automatically work for components, even when an `<input>` is the single root element. The component must explicitly implement the `v-model` interface (i.e., receive a `modelValue` prop, and emit the `update:modelValue` event):

```html
<template>
  <input :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CustomInput',
  props: ['modelValue'],
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-inherit-attrs?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FCustomInput.vue)

Comment: tony19 is there any way to inherit the directive ??

Comment: No, I don't think that's possible. You'd have to update the directive itself to reach into the component, where needed.